# Compare two mobile hardwares programmatically

Tags: android, performance, cpu

I am doing an Android VOIP app. I would like to choose my codec type based on the cpu performance. Certain audio codecs don't perform well on certain low end devices. I would like to decide this programmatically and not at the compile time. What are the yardsticks that will help in deciding the cpu performance and available bandwidth for processing:

Here are some of them that I can think of:

1) CPU clock cycle
2) Available Memory

Is there a standard way for deciding the processing power based on the cpu/memory stats?

It would be great to know whether Android provides api for performance analysis in the run-time.

Answer (score 0):

There are companies that provide these services.

For most, you simply send the device's make, model, version .etc. and you get a response describing the capabilities of the device, such as RAM, CPU .etc. and also what file formats are supported to play, whether your device have a accelerometer, does it support HTML 5 ....

Quick Google search gave me http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

There are lot of providers, both paid and free. I cannot recommend any, as I've never used them.